# Is it possible to set hyperlink style within a specific DIV only

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm making a pure javascript webapp (no JQuery), that generates all the content in run-time. There are no CSS files to be loaded, all styles are generated by JS.

For example:

```
function newParagraph(content,x,y,w,h)
{
    var obj = document.createElement("div");
    obj.style.position = "absolute";
    obj.style.left = x + "px";
    obj.style.top = y + "px";
    obj.style.width = w + "px";
    obj.style.height = h + "px";
    obj.style.fontFamily = ..... some web font
    obj.style.fontSize = "20px";
    obj.style.fontWeight = "normal";
    obj.style.fontVariant = "small-caps";
    .... etc ....
    obj.innerHTML = content;
    return obj;
}
```

Above function will create a div object, of specified size and absolute position, will set font style and put paragraph content in innerHTML.

This content may contain  object.

I know I can set hyperlink style in page css. I don't want that. I want to set hyperlink style only within the scope of a specific DIV object. So different DIV objects will have hyperlinks appear in different styles.

Is that possible, and if so, how?

Comment: It would be great if a down-vote would be accompanied with a comment, to explain why. It would help me improve my future questions.

Comment: Shouldn't a function called *newParagraph* create a paragraph element, not a div? ;-)

Comment: @RobG, you are correct, function name is misleading. Paragraph here does not refer to HTML <p> object, rather from webapp's perspective how final result will look like to end user.

Comment: A "pure javascript" web app can still use CSS rather than set every style property individually. At the very least create a *setProps* function that loops over a set of properties and values in an object to set an element's properties rather than one statement per property.

Comment: @RobG Thank you for your input, and webapp will still use page CSS for styles that are constant. In this case, I need to show different chunks of text, each with it's own (random) style (which also includes hyperlink style for <a> object within one chunk of text)

Comment: If you use a *setProps* function you could have the function randomise settings… `setProps(el, {style: {font: 'random', backgroundColor:'vermillion'}})`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in different way but it is not by default something you should do inline.

One way is to simulate it with JavaScript

```
<a
  href="/path/file.html"
  onMouseOver="this.style.color='#0F0'"
  onMouseOut="this.style.color='#00F'"
 >YourLink</a>
```

It is also possible to do it with Html. See example 2.3 of W3.org (http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css-style-attr-20020515)

```
 <a href="http://www.w3.org/"
      style="{color: #900}
      :link {background: #ff0}
      :visited {background: #fff}
      :hover {outline: thin red solid}
      :active {background: #00f}">...</a>
```

From that info you can set the style with JavaScript or set the OnMouse function with JavaScript in your method.

Comment: Ok but problem is that I get paragraph content, which may or may not contain <a> object. So basically, the only way is to set style for each <a> encountered in the content of DIV? There's no way to set <a> style which is "local" style for entire DIV content?

Comment: @Sinisa—the selector `div a {...}` applies to A elements in a div. Anchors (A elements with no HREF) are invisible and don't need content, so it doesn't matter if it selects one.

Comment: @RobG, my understanding is that selector 'div a' would set style for all <a> in all <div>. While I need to set style for 'a' for each 'div' separately as it will differ one from another.

Answer (score 1):

set the href from your script and for styling that particular href you can use the css attribute selector like

```
a[href^="http://stackoverflow.com"] { 
    color: red; 
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

It ensures that only href="http://stackoverflow.com" is styled.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/u2awL742/)**

Answer (score -1):

Ok I found the solution, but if anyone has better idea, please do post the answer, I will accept it!

Here it is:

```
function newParagraph(content,x,y,w,h)
{
    var obj = document.createElement("div");
    obj.style.position = "absolute";
    obj.style.left = x + "px";
    obj.style.top = y + "px";
    .... etc ....
    obj.innerHTML = content;
    var childobj = obj.firstChild;
    while(childobj)
    {
        if( childobj.href !== undefined ) // this has hyperlink
            childobj.style.color = ..... hyperlink color ....
        childobj = childobj.nextSibling;
    }
    return obj;
}
```